# Using Salesforce as identity provider for my web app and Community portal

Tags: community, single-sign-on

I have a Salesforce Communities site w/ user base set up, and I also have a custom web app (a CMS). I'm trying to allow my customers to log into my web app using their Salesforce username/password, while also logging them into the Community.

I don't necessarily need OAuth or SAML, but I'm very confused as to how I can/can't accomplish this with Salesforce. I've done something like this in the past with another "identity provider" where customer enters their username/password to my web app, the web app then calls an API to the identity provider, it validates the credentials and returns a user object along with a session id. I then set up an active session for them on my web app, and when they need to jump over to the identity provider's site, I can jump them over w/ the session id to let them in.

My instinct was to use the Salesforce enterprise SOAP API, and then frontdoor.jsp. I've tested this with some success, but the login() SOAP api method seemed to only work when I provided an OrgId *and* PortalId.  I'm trying to authenticate users of the Salesforce Communities site, and then frontdoor them into the Community, not the portal.

Are there any resources that explain how to accomplish this?

Sample code:

```
loginClient = new SoapClient();

var lr = loginClient.login(new LoginScopeHeader
{
    organizationId = "{my org id}",
    //portalId = "??"  <-- not sure if this is necessary?
}, username, password);

var sessionId = lr.sessionId;

// TODO: compose frontdoor url with session id
```

Frontdoor.jsp says to compose a url w/ the following structure `https://instance.salesforce.com/secur/frontdoor.jsp?sid=full_sessionID_value​&retURL=optional_relative_url_to_open`  but my communities portal is of the url structure `https://my-community-name.cs27.force.com`.  I tried https://my-community-name.cs27.force.com/secur/frontdoor.jsp?sid=mysessionid but just got a page telling me to log in.

I understand the frontdoor documentation states "Not all session types are supported with frontdoor.jsp, such as community API sessions. For these sessions, consider using SAML for single sign-on, instead."  But I don't even know what a "Community API session" means. I'm just using the regular SOAP api to call a login() method - what type of session is that?

Comment: @ABretto This question is quite old. Have you tried using SSO with Salesforce as Identity provider, instead the code based approach posted in this question? Some of the configuration depends on the service provider's capabilities as well. IMO, this question might not have all the details required to work out  a feasible solution. I would suggest you provide some specific details from your end or post a new question.